# JSON.Stringfy method's replacer argument not working on nested object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object, I want to send this object's simplified version to the server.

```
{
 "fullName": "Don Corleone",
 "actor": {
  "actorId": 2,
  "name": "Marlon",
  "surname": "Brando",
  "description": "Marlon Brando is widely considered the greatest movie actor of all time... ",
  "heroList": [],
  "photo": "C:\\projects\\files\\actor\\1532955376934.png"
 },
 "heroProfilePhoto": "data:image/png;base64,/9j/...
 "production": {
  "title": "The Godfather",
  "imdbRate": 9.2,
  "genre": "8",
  "releaseDate": "1972-03-23T21:00:00.000Z",
  "director": "Francis Ford Coppola",
  "writer": "Mari Puzo",
  "detail": "The aging patriarch of an organized crime dynasty transfers control of his clandestine empire to his reluctant son."
 }
}"
```

I have two question::

1) Is it possible to extract something like this with [replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) of [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) ?

```
 {
  "fullName": "Don Corleone",
  "actor": {
   "actorId": 2
   }
}"
```

2) At least can I extract something like this with [replacer parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter) of [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)?

```
{
 "fullName": "Don Corleone",
 "actor": {
  "actorId": 2,
  "name": "Marlon",
  "surname": "Brando",
  "description": "Marlon Brando is widely considered the greatest movie actor of all time... ",
  "heroList": [],
  "photo": "C:\\projects\\files\\actor\\1532955376934.png"
 },
}"
```

When I am using like this it's okay:

`JSON.stringify(hero, ['fullName'])` Result -> `"{"fullName":"Don Corleone"}"`

But this :

`JSON.stringify(hero, ['fullName', 'actor'])` Result -> `"{"fullName":"Don Corleone","actor":{}}"`

Why actor property is empty?

Comment: You have not specified any other properties than the actor & fullname, and the actor is indeed been sent.  If you want more inside the actor, you need to select that too.. eg. -. `JSON.stringify(hero, ['fullName', 'actor', 'name'])`

Comment: O I have tried this: JSON.stringify(hero, ['fullName', 'actorId']) and than it returned 
-> "{"fullName":"Don Corleone"}"

But this: JSON.stringify(hero, ['fullName', 'actor', 'actorId']) returned the what I want -> "{"fullName":"Don Corleone","actor":{"actorId":2}}"

Thank you. So before 
'actorId I have to add 'actor' property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`JSON.stringify` requires you pass in all of the data you would like returned. `'actor'` on its own is not enough.

You want:

`JSON.stringify(hero, ['fullName', 'actor', 'actorId'])`

EDIT

So I've done some testing, I was curious what would happen if `actorId` also existed in the parent object, and the results are in.

Both `actorId` fields are returned by JSON.stringify() in the case where `actorId` exists inside of the `actor` object, and inside the parent object. If you would like this not to be the case, you will have to create a more complex function for your needs and pass it to JSON.stringify() as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Here's some examples:

```
var json = {
    key1: "Value for key1 in parent",
    key2: {
        key3: "Value for key3 in child",
        key4: "Value for key4 in child"
    },
    key4: "Value for key4 in parent"
}

var out1 = JSON.stringify(json, ['key1', 'key3'])
/*
out1 = {
    key1: "Value for key1 in parent"
} // No key3!
*/


var out2 = JSON.stringify(json, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3'])
/*
out2 = {
    key1: "Value for key1 in parent",
    key2: {
        key3: "Value for key3 in child"
    }
}
*/

var out3 = JSON.stringify(json, ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4'])
/*
out3 = {
    key1: "Value for key1 in parent",
    key2: {
        key3: "Value for key3 in child",
        key4: "Value for key4 in child" // Both key4 returned
    },
    key4: "Value for key4 in parent" // Both key4 returned
}
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Easily we can get by using Spread in object literals

Try to read the Object like

`const obj = {yourObj.fullname, yourObj.actor}
const yourAnswer = JSON.stringify(obj)`

you can refer the link
[Spread_syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

since JSON.stringify is very slow for large objects, try to use above method

Comment: What I look is the  JSON.stringify() because of the simplicity of 'stringify'.
Thank you 'Ananth' .

Comment: since JSON.stringify is very slow for large objects, should we prefer Spread in object literals